# Split data in one worksheet to multiple worksheets based on column in Excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split data in sheet 1 to multiple sheets based on the name column in cell A3 onwards. The problem that I am facing is I’m unable to track down the data if there are gap in between. Example the name starts from A3 to A100 and in between cell A10, A20 & A30 is empty the program will only track down value from A3 to A9. The other problem for me is to specify the header. The header that I want to use start from cell A2, B2, C2 & D2 and this program show the header as A1, B1, C1 & D1 as there are value in that cell. This is my code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, cc
Dim temp As Worksheet, CostC As Range, u

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'where your original data. adjust to suit
Set Rng = ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 15)
Set CostC = ws.Range("a3", ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

u = UNIQUE(CostC)
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
For Each cc In u
    With Rng
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & cc
        On Error Resume Next
        Set temp = Sheets(cc)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not temp Is Nothing Then

DoThis:

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy temp.Range("A1")
        Else
            Set temp = Sheets.Add
            temp.Name = cc
            GoTo DoThis
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Set temp = Nothing
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

End Sub

Function UNIQUE(r As Range)
Dim a, v
If IsArray(r.Value) Then
    a = r.Value
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .comparemode = vbTextCompare
        For Each v In a
            If Not IsEmpty(v) Then
                If Not .exists(v) Then .Add v, Nothing
            End If
        Next
        If .Count > 0 Then UNIQUE = .keys
    End With
    Erase a
Else
    UNIQUE = r.Value
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried changing any of that code? Looks like it's exactly as originally posted 2008.  Maybe first have a go yourself at modifying it to meet your needs?

Comment: Yeah, i have modified the cell location.

Comment: I tried to skip empty cell using If CostC <> "" but have a run time error.

Comment: Is it just the name cell which is empty, or the entire row?

Comment: The entire row. Example A1 to A10 in between A5 is empty it will only paste value from A1 to A4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly less-optimized but simpler to follow version:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet,  c As Range
Dim temp As Worksheet, CostC As Range, u

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 

Set CostC = ws.Range(ws.Range("A3"), ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For each c in CostC.Cells

    u = trim(c.Value)
    If len(u) > 0 then

        Set temp = Nothing '<<EDIT
        On Error Resume Next
        Set temp = Sheets(u)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If temp is Nothing then
            Set temp = Sheets.Add()
            ws.Range("A2").Resize(1, 15).Copy temp.range("a1") 'copy headers
            temp.Name = u
        End If

        c.resize(1, 15).copy temp.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0)

     End if 'have name

Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Mate, based on this code it only open a single sheet and compile everything in to that sheet. What i wanted to do is to open multiple worksheets based on the name in cell A3 onwards. The name can be repetitive example John, Jane & Jack. If the name in sheet 1 is John and it appear 10 times than it will go to a new sheet name after John and will also copy down the age size in cell b,c etc. My problem is i am not able to track down the data if the cell is empty in between. Example if cell A20 is empty than it will only show the data up to cell A19 in a new sheets based on the name.

Comment: See my edit - I should have added "untested" to the previous version ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ColumnDifferences` method to return a range and then use the `Areas(1)` property of that range to copy the data into a new worksheet and then you can delete the data and repeat, or loop through the areas and copy them.